# Как правильно делать такую форму регистрации?

Tags: css3, html5

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="phone">Телефон:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="text">Оставьте сообщение, и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" required>
  </p>



  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит - как правильно? Да и судя по скрину, это figma, там все стили указаны. Просто надо взять и перенести их...

Comment: То что там написано это я переписал, я же спрашивал про то как правильно оформлять input например где телефоне  у меня написано type="text" это считается неправильным названием.

Comment: В вашем вопросе есть заголовок, кусох HTML и картинка... кто его знает, что вы хотите. По поводу инпутов: type - это не название, а тип поля. Кто вам сказал, что оно не правильное? Возможно, вы имели ввиду, что у него тип не правильный, с точки зрения логики... [Вот все виды type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) - выбирайте наиболее подходящий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

input,
textarea,
button {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

input {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

textarea {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

label {
  color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <label>Имя
    <input type="text">
  </label>
    <label>Телефон
    <input type="tel">
  </label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Оставьте сообщение и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать правильно). Один из способов, так сказать)

Comment: @The__Tipучусь, если нужно, чтобы и при фокусе поля формы оставались неизменными, т.е. только с нижней серой границей в один пиксель, то добавьте в css: 
`input, textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
`